# GUI with Reversi, refuses to wait for players move java

Tags: java, user-interface, artificial-intelligence

I wrote a Reversi program that makes a gui filled with a 2d array of buttons. there are several methods including validMoves() which makes the valid moves setEnabled(true); and shows a red dot so the user knows which buttons are active. it also flips the correct tiles when you pick which tile you want to move. 
the problem i am running into is that the gui doesn't wait for the player to make a move. i wrote an ai which basically is the exact same as the player it finds the valid moves, finds which one will flip the most tiles and returns it in the format "x*y" which my method will then substring into x and y and make the move and flip the tiles.
i tried thread.sleep() and wait() and a while (!hasMoved) and a bunch of other things it just doesn't want to cooperate. 
with the wait() i run into an infinite loop bc the gui is there but nothing is in it. however when i comment the wait out it shows up exactly as it should.

```
package reversi;
/*
 * bugs need to make it check the edges too // it goes out of bounds
 * refresh scores doesnt work
 *
 * add clear all readys after someone does a move
 */
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Timer;

/**
 * @author 13ponchera
 * the board for reversi that will play the game
 */
public class ReversiBoard extends JApplet
{
    private int score1;
    private int score2;
    private int turn;
    private Icon p1 = new ImageIcon("images/p1.png");
    private Icon p2 = new ImageIcon("images/p2.png");
    private Icon bGround = new ImageIcon("images/bGround.png");
    private Icon ready = new ImageIcon("images/ready.png");
    // will help the action listener determin which players turn it is
    private int x; // the number of buttons
    private JButton[][] buttons;
    private JPanel settingPanel =
            new JPanel();
    private JButton newGame =
            new JButton("New Game?");
    private JLabel score1A;
    private JLabel score2A;
    private JPanel gameBoard =
            new JPanel();
    private AI ai = new AI(bGround,p1,p2);
    private boolean hasMoved;
    private Timer t;
    /**
     * Initialization method that
     * will be called after the applet is loaded
     * into the browser.
     * sets up everything
     */
    public  void init()
    {
        score1 = 0;
        score2 = 0;
        // sets the viewer to say the score
        score1A = new JLabel("Player: " + score1);
        score2A = new JLabel("Computer:" + score2);

        //adds components to the setting panel
        settingPanel.add(newGame);
            newGame.addActionListener(new NewGameListener());
        settingPanel.add(score1A);//initialized at 0
        settingPanel.add(score2A);

        //creates a game board of any size as long as it is an even number
        String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null, "please enter an even integer for x");
            x = Integer.parseInt(a) + 2;
        if ((x % 2 == 0) && (x > 4))
        {
            gameBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(x, x, 4, 4));
            buttons = new JButton[x][x];
        }// add 2 to x then set the edges to a new picture
        else
        {
            //asks for a new number untill number is even
            while ((x % 2 != 0) && (x < 4))
            {
                String responce = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                        (null, "Must be an even "
                        + "number rows and collums \n\tplease enter x");
                x = Integer.parseInt(responce) + 2;
            }
            gameBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(x, x, 4, 4));
            buttons = new JButton[x][x];
        }

        //creates the buttons for each slot and puts them into a 2d array
        for (int c = 0; c < x; c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < x; d++)
            {
                buttons[c][d] = new JButton();
                buttons[c][d].setIcon(bGround);
                    // adds the background default pict
                buttons[c][d].addActionListener
                        (new ButtonListener(buttons[c][d],c,d));
                    // adds a generic button listener
                buttons[c][d].setEnabled(false);
                    // the buttons are non clickable except for the valid moves
                gameBoard.add(buttons[c][d]);
                buttons[c][d].setIcon(bGround);
                buttons[c][d].setDisabledIcon(bGround);
                    // adds the buttons to the jpanel
            }
        }

        //makes the edges a different color
        // adds the jpanel with all of the buttons into the content pane

        buttons[x/2][x/2]
                .setIcon(p1);
        buttons[x/2][x/2]
                .setDisabledIcon(p1);
        buttons[(x/2) - 1][(x/2) - 1]
                .setIcon(p1);
        buttons[(x/2) - 1][(x/2) - 1]
                .setDisabledIcon(p1);
                        refreshTable();
                // makes the middle upper left and lower right white pieces

        buttons[(x/2) - 1][(x/2)]
                .setIcon(p2);
        buttons[x/2][(x/2) - 1]
                .setIcon(p2);
        buttons[(x/2) - 1][(x/2)]
                .setDisabledIcon(p2);
        buttons[x/2][(x/2) - 1]
                .setDisabledIcon(p2);

                        refreshTable();
                // makes the midle upper right and lower left black pieces

        getContentPane()
                .add(gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        getContentPane();//burp the applet
        // after two days of hitting my head on the keyboard

        getContentPane()
                .add(settingPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                //adds the setting panel (new game button
                //and scores to the content pane)
        refreshTable();
        t = new Timer();

        hasMoved = false;
        validMoves();
        refreshTable();
        synchronized(t)
        {
            while(!hasMoved)
            {
                try
                {
                    t.wait(50);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReversiBoard.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        refreshTable();
        aiTurn();


        // make the edges a different picture
    }

    /**
     * refreshes the table so that pictures will appear
     */
    public  void refreshTable()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < x; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < x; b++)
            {
                buttons[a][b].repaint();
            }
        }
        setScores();
        score1A.setText
                ("Player: " + score1);
        score2A.setText
                ("Computer: " + score2);
        gameBoard.repaint();
        settingPanel.repaint();

    }

    /**
     * finds all the valid moves and sets the
     * buttons enabled and gives them an identifiable picture
     */
    public  void validMoves()
    {
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        // temperary values so search can go on uninterupted

        for(int a = 1; a < x - 1; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 1; b < x - 1; b++)
            {
                //looks at every tile
                if (buttons[a][b].getIcon() ==bGround)
                {
                    //if it is a background child look to
                    //see if there is an enemy peace adjacent
                   if (buttons[a + 1][b].getIcon() == p2)
                   {
                       // keeps checking that direction
                       //until it runs to the end of the
                       //board or hits an ally
                       // c is the cordinates of where it finds
                       c = a + 1;
                       while ((buttons[c][b].getIcon() == p2)
                               && (c < x)
                               && (c > 0))
                       {
                           if (buttons[c + 1][b].getIcon() == p1)
                           {
                               buttons[a][b].setEnabled(true);
                               buttons[a][b]
                                       .setIcon(ready);

                             //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
                           }
                           c++;

                       }
                   }
                   //see if there is an enemy peace adjacent
                   if (buttons[a - 1][b].getIcon() == p2)
                   {
                       // keeps checking that direction
                       //until it runs to the end of the
                       //board or hits an ally
                       // c is the cordinates of where it finds
                       c = a - 1;
                       while ((buttons[c][b].getIcon() == p2)
                               && (c < x)
                               && (c > 0))
                       {
                           if (buttons[c - 1][b].getIcon() == p1)
                           {
                               buttons[a][b].setEnabled(true);
                               buttons[a][b]
                                       .setIcon(ready);

                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
                           }
                           c--;

                       }
                   }


                   if (buttons[a][b + 1].getIcon() == p2)
                   {
                       // keeps checking that direction
                       //until it runs to the end of the
                       //board or hits an ally
                       // c is the cordinates of where it finds
                       c = b + 1;
                       while ((buttons[a][c].getIcon() == p2)
                               && (c < x)
                               && (c > 0))
                       {
                           if (buttons[a][c + 1].getIcon() == p1)
                           {
                               buttons[a][b].setEnabled(true);
                               buttons[a][b]
                                       .setIcon(ready);

                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
                           }
                           c++;

                       }
                   }
                   if (buttons[a][b - 1].getIcon() == p2)
                   {
                       // keeps checking that direction
                       //until it runs to the end of the
                       //board or hits an ally
                       // c is the cordinates of where it finds
                       c = b - 1;
                       while ((buttons[a][c].getIcon() == p2)
                               && (c < x)
                               && (c > 0))
                       {
                           if (buttons[a][c - 1].getIcon() == p1)
                           {
                               buttons[a][b].setEnabled(true);
                               buttons[a][b]
                                       .setIcon(ready);

                                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
                           }
                           c--;

                       }
                   }
                   //starts checking diagonals
                   if (buttons[a + 1][b + 1].getIcon() == p2)
                   {
                       // keeps checking that direction
                       //until it runs to the end of the
                       //board or hits an ally
                       // c is the cordinates of where it finds
                       c = a + 1;
                       d = b + 1;
                       while ((buttons[c][d].getIcon() == p2)
                               && (c < x)
                               && (c > 0)
                               && (d < x)
                               && (d > 0))
                       {
                           if (buttons[c + 1][d + 1].getIcon() == p1)
                           {
                               buttons[a][b].setEnabled(true);
                               buttons[a][b]
                                       .setIcon(ready);
                              // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
                           }
                           c++;
                           d++;

                       }
                   }
                   if (buttons[a - 1][b - 1].getIcon() == p2)
                   {
                       // keeps checking that direction
                       //until it runs to the end of the
                       //board or hits an ally
                       // c is the cordinates of where it finds
                       c = a - 1;
                       d = b - 1;
                       while ((buttons[c][d].getIcon() == p2)
                               && (c < x)
                               && (c > 0)
                               && (d < x)
                               && (d > 0))
                       {
                           if (buttons[c - 1][d -1].getIcon() == p1)
                           {
                               buttons[a][b].setEnabled(true);
                               buttons[a][b]
                                       .setIcon(ready);

                             //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
                           }
                           c--;
                           d--;

                       }
                   }
                   if (buttons[a - 1][b + 1].getIcon() == p2)
                   {
                       // keeps checking that direction
                       //until it runs to the end of the
                       //board or hits an ally
                       // c is the cordinates of where it finds
                       c = a - 1;
                       d = b + 1;
                       while ((buttons[c][d].getIcon() == p2)
                               && (c < x)
                               && (c > 0)
                               && (d < x)
                               && (d > 0))
                       {
                           if (buttons[c - 1][d + 1].getIcon() == p1)
                           {
                               buttons[a][b].setEnabled(true);
                               buttons[a][b]
                                       .setIcon(ready);

                           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
                           }
                           c--;
                           d++;

                       }
                   }
                   if (buttons[a + 1][b - 1].getIcon() == p2)
                   {
                       // keeps checking that direction
                       //until it runs to the end of the
                       //board or hits an ally
                       // c is the cordinates of where it finds
                       c = a + 1;
                       d = b - 1;
                       while ((buttons[c][d].getIcon() == p2)
                               && (c < x)
                               && (c > 0)
                               && (d < x)
                               && (d > 0))
                       {
                           if (buttons[c + 1][d - 1].getIcon() == p1)
                           {
                               buttons[a][b].setEnabled(true);
                               buttons[a][b]
                                       .setIcon(ready);

                           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"");
                           }
                           c++;
                           d--;

                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        refreshTable();
        /*try
        {
            Thread.sleep(50); // 30 seconds NA
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ReversiBoard.class.getName())
                    .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * calculates the scores of each player
     */

    /**
     *
     * @return boolean if game is over
     */
    public  boolean winner()
    {
        refreshTable();
        if (!anyMove(1) && !anyMove(0))
            return true;
            //joptionpan the winner (if score1 > score 2).... and vv
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param player 1 for player 1 for computer
     * @return boolean if there is a move
     */


    public  void clearReady()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < x; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < x; b++)
            {
                if (buttons[a][b].getIcon() == ready)
                {
                    buttons[a][b].setIcon(bGround);
                    buttons[a][b].setEnabled(false);
                    buttons[a][b].setDisabledIcon(bGround);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private  void makeMove(String move)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        char[] f = move.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
        {
            if (f[i] == ('*'))
                temp = i;
        }
        int x = Integer.parseInt(move.substring(0,temp));
        int y = Integer.parseInt(move.substring(temp + 1));

        buttons[x][y].setIcon(p2);
        buttons[x][y].setEnabled(false);
        buttons[x][y].setDisabledIcon(p2);

        flip(1,x,y);
    }


    private void aiTurn()
    {
        String move = ai.makeMove(buttons);
            // string move is a string with cordinates seperated by a *
        makeMove(move);
        turn++;
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        private JButton a;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        private ButtonListener(JButton jButton, int c, int d)
        {
            a = jButton;
            x = c;
            y = d;
        }

        public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //must differentiate between p1 and p2
            switch (turn % 2)
            {
                case 0:
                    a.setIcon(p1);
                    a.setEnabled(false);
                    a.setDisabledIcon(p1);
                    flip(0,x,y);
                    turn++;
                    clearReady();
                    hasMoved = true;
                    /*synchronized(t)
                    {
                        t.notifyAll();
                    }*/
                    refreshTable();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    a.setIcon(p2);
                    a.setEnabled(false);
                    a.setDisabledIcon(p2);
                    flip(1,x,y);
                    turn++;
                    clearReady();
                    hasMoved = true;
                    /*synchronized(t)
                    {
                        t.notifyAll();
                    }*/
                    refreshTable();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: refreshTable();
        t = new Timer();

        hasMoved = false;
        validMoves();
        refreshTable();
        synchronized(t)
        {
            while(!hasMoved)
            {
                try
                {
                    t.wait(50);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReversiBoard.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        refreshTable();
        aiTurn();     it shows up weirdly in this edit

Comment: You should post your code in the question (edit the question) instead of the comments, and indicate which language (it looks like Java) and which GUI framework you're using (Swing, Awt, SWT ?)

Comment: thx i fixed it i had to leave out the AI and some of the methods to make it fit

Comment: so i am still trying to fix it for myself - i tried putting getContentPane().repaint(); it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below how your GUI application should behave (more or less) :

1. create the widgets
2. register listeners to the widgets
3. wait for user action
4. update the Gui to display user's move
5. call the AI to do its move and display it
6. go back to point 3

You already have done the points 1 and 2 done in your `init` method. You should remove the last part of this method (the block with the `while(!hasMoved)` loop) : it's the point 3, and it is handled by the Applet after the `init` is finished. You have nothing to do.

When the user clicks on a JButton (provided the button is enabled), the method `actionPerformed` of `ButtonListener` is called: its the start of point 4, you should update your widgets (`refreshTable()` in your code), and make the AI move (`aiTurn()`, point 5). When the method `actionPerformed` is finsihed, the JApplet goes back automatically to point 3, you've nothing to do.

I don't know Applets very well, so I can't be more precise. You should search for JApplet examples/tutorials with similar behaviors as yours. Remember you should not have infinite loops in your code waiting for user's input : it's handled by the JApplet.

Comment: so i should add at the end of the action listener aiTurn(); and ValidMoves();?

Comment: you are a genius it works fine now i have to fix the ai now because it is askew but it works thanks so much